# Can get information (.get)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to fetch information from a public website area. 
Let's just say I want the Product name and a Price of it only.
When I try to get the information from the site it  giving me an error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `'http://demo.com'` is therefore not allowed access.

The script I use is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://www.ebay.com", function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
});
```

Comment: Please help me understand the problem and give some examples from ebay or another sites.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: you are not authorised to get that page from the clientside. Read about [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If you want to access eBay's prices from the clientside, the correct way is to use their [API](https://go.developer.ebay.com/what-ebay-api), not to scrape the human-facing pages.